# react redux persist combining reducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I'm developing an e-commerce web app using react typescript and node js,
in which I'm using @reduxjs/toolkit to manage states and redux-persist to save a state to local storage.
I have two reducers, cart reducer to manage shopping cart:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/createAction";
import { cart, product } from "../models";
import { toasterSuccess, toasterWarning } from "../shared/toaster";

export interface CartState {
  cartItems: cart[];
}

const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state: CartState, action: PayloadAction<product>) => {
      const producutIndex = state.cartItems.findIndex(
        (item) => item._id === action.payload._id
      );
      if (producutIndex === -1) {
        let newCartItem: cart = {
          _id: action.payload._id,
          name: action.payload.name,
          brand: action.payload.brand,
          quantity: 1,
          price: action.payload.price,
          total: action.payload.price,
          image: action.payload.image,
        };
        state.cartItems.push(newCartItem);
        toasterSuccess("Product added to you cart .");
      } else toasterWarning("Product is already in your cart .");
    },
    removeFromCart: (state: CartState, action: PayloadAction<cart>) => {
      const removeItem = state.cartItems.filter(
        (item) => item._id !== action.payload._id
      );
      state.cartItems = removeItem;
    },
    updateCartItemQuantity: (state: CartState, action: PayloadAction<cart>) => {
      const item = state.cartItems.find(
        (item) => item._id === action.payload._id
      );
      item!.quantity = action.payload.quantity;
    },
  },
});

export const cartReducer = cartSlice.reducer;
export const { addToCart, removeFromCart, updateCartItemQuantity } =
  cartSlice.actions;
```

product reducer to manage product list:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { filter, product } from "../models";
import {
  GetBrands,
  GetCategories,
  GetProducts,
} from "../shared/apis/productApi";

export interface ProductState {
  products: product[];
  productsScroll: product[];
  brands: string[];
  categories: string[];
  hasMore: boolean;
}

const initialState = {
  products: [],
  productsScroll: [],
  brands: [],
  categories: [],
  hasMore: true,
} as ProductState;

export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/list",
  async (filter: filter) => {
    const response = await GetProducts(filter);
    return response.Body;
  }
);

export const fetchCategories = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/categories",
  async () => {
    const response = await GetCategories();
    return response.Body;
  }
);

export const fetchBrands = createAsyncThunk("products/brands", async () => {
  const response = await GetBrands();
  return response.Body;
});

const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    emptyScroll: (state: ProductState) => {
      state.productsScroll = [];
      state.hasMore = true;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state: ProductState, action) => {
      state.productsScroll.push(...action.payload!.products);
      state.products = action.payload!.products;
      if (state.products && state.products.length === action.payload!.count)
        state.hasMore = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(
      fetchCategories.fulfilled,
      (state: ProductState, action) => {
        state.categories = action.payload!;
      }
    );
    builder.addCase(fetchBrands.fulfilled, (state: ProductState, action) => {
      state.brands = action.payload!;
    });
  },
});

export const productReducer = productSlice.reducer;
export const { emptyScroll } = productSlice.actions;
```

and the store configuration:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { cartReducer } from "../slices/cartSlice";

import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
  PersistConfig,
} from "redux-persist";
import { productReducer } from "../slices/productSlice";

const persistConfig: PersistConfig<any> = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  blacklist: ["product"],
};

const rootReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  combineReducers({
    cart: cartReducer,
    product: productReducer,
  })
);
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

and this is the App.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Views from "./shared/components/views";
import "./App.css";
import { AuthProvider } from "./contexts/authContext";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/lib/integration/react";
import { persistor, store } from "./stores";
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Router>
            <ToastContainer />
            <Views />
          </Router>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the idea here is to persist only the cart reducer and suppress the persisting of the product reducer.

the persistence seems to work correctly when I check the local storage and the states two when I check the dev-tools.
the problem is I get an error when I call the dispatch of a cart or product in any component.

what I'm doing wrong here ??

thanks a lot.

Comment: What does "an error" say? I suppose it has text?

Comment: @phry whne i load my product components, i have a function where i map through the product state, the error says "can't read property map of undefined".

Comment: Then please add the line of code where you get the error up there - that's the most important related code!